# Simulation vs Formal Analysis of Authentication Protocols

Tags: authentication, attacks, protocols, tools, cryptanalysis

I received a review for my journal paper in which we proposed WOOlim or nspk kind of authentication protocols. We proved the strength of our protocol with rigorous formal methods using CSP and rank function analysis as well as we proved the strength against known attacks with examples but reviewer asked us to show the strength with experiment or simulation.

Is it not sufficient to prove the strength with formal analysis? And what kind of tools can be used to simulate authentication protocol? I implemented my scheme in an automated security protocol analysis tool, SCYTHER, but its a kind of tool which in fact prove the protocol claims with formal analysis, we can not consider it a simulation.

Comment: In my opinion what can be formally proved should not need a simulation. Maybe a simulation is more visual appealing but not more formal in my opinion.